# Relationship auto-indexing in Neo4J 3.x vs 2.x

Tags: neo4j, cypher

In Neo4J 2.x I used auto-indexing of relationships, which then allowed me to do search based on relationship properties that were indexed.

In Neo4J 3.x this doesn't work.

In Neo4J 2.x I'd set in `neo4j properties`:

`relationship_auto_indexing=true`

and set several properties of relationships to be indexed using

`relationship_keys_indexable=user,context,statement,gapscan`

Then I would use the old 1.x Cypher query to first identify all the relationships made by the user of the type `TO`, reading their context property and then matching it to the node that had a specific Context property and then matching the nodes from that context made by that user and retrieving them. The query looked something like

`START rel=relationship:relationship_auto_index(user='userid') WHERE TYPE(rel)='TO' WITH DISTINCT rel MATCH (ctx:Context) WHERE rel.context = ctx.uid AND (ctx.name="neo4j3" ) RETURN DISTINCT STARTNODE(rel).uid AS source_id, STARTNODE(rel).name AS source_name, ENDNODE(rel).uid AS target_id, ENDNODE(rel).name AS target_name, rel.uid AS edge_id, ctx.name AS context_name, rel.statement AS statement_id, rel.weight AS weight;`

In Neo4J 3.x this query doesn't work and I believe the indexing is done differently.

I have two questions:

1) Do I have to manually index relationship or it is done automatically in 3.x?

2) What query would I use instead of `START rel=....` — any alternative to search using relationship properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the same thing in 3.X, but differently.

Yes, you have to index the relationship manually.
With `APOC` you can create a manual index for your relationships.

This is the query to populate your index :

```
MATCH ()-[r:MY_RELATIONSHIPS]->()
CALL apoc.index.addRelationship(r,['user'])
RETURN count(*)
```

An then you can retrieve your relationships like than :

```
CALL apoc.index.relationships('MY_RELATIONSHIPS','userid:userid') YIELD rel, start , end
RETURN rel, start, end
```

Link to the doc : https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_using_manual_index_on_relationship_properties

Moreover, to automacly populate your manual index, you can also create a trigger with apoc (https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_triggers_examples)

Comment: Great, thanks, @logisima. The only correction I have is that my request should be modified to `CALL apoc.index.relationships('MY_RELATIONSHIPS','user:userid') YIELD rel, start, end
WITH DISTINCT rel, start, end MATCH (ctx:Context) WHERE rel.context = ctx.uid AND (ctx.name="neo4j3" ) RETURN DISTINCT start.uid AS source_id, start.name AS source_name, end.uid AS target_id, end.name AS target_name, rel.uid AS edge_id, ctx.name AS context_name, rel.statement AS statement_id, rel.weight AS weight;`

Comment: I couldn't find how to populate manual index for relationships... could not see any examples there... I understand the concept but they don't talk about the relationship index trigger

Comment: I figured it out. Had to run something like `CALL apoc.trigger.add('Index-TO-Relationships',"UNWIND {createdRelationships} AS r MATCH ()-[r:TO]->() CALL apoc.index.addRelationship(r,['user']) RETURN count(*)", {phase:'after'})` to add the index on the relationships. (Enabling triggers first in the `conf` file).